# Erro ao realizar update no laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent, model

Ao tentar realizar o seguinte update:

```
        $criterios = Criterios::find(1);

        $criterios->update(
                    [
                        'criterios' => $request->criterios
                        'editado_por' => $user->id
                    ]
                );
```

Eu recebo o erro: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (Thu 23 Apr 16:40:16 2020) at position 13 (:): Unexpected character

O insert é feito corretamente, não tenho nenhum mutator, segue meu model:

```
class Criterios extends Model
{
        protected $table = 'criterios';

        protected $fillable = ['criterios', 'editado_por']
}
```

Comment: Não dá pra saber só com esse código.

Answer (score -1):

Tenta o seguinte.

```
$criterios = Criterios::find(1);
$criterios->criterios = $request->get('name_do_input');
$criterios->editado_por = $request->get('name_do_input');
$criterios->save();
```